# Coiled wire around connector terminal, what do I call this, and how do you do it?

Tags: wire, terminal

Please consider the following image:

[image]

I randomly wandered into the telecom room at work a while ago, and I noticed these strange looking terminals. How do you terminate a wire like this? Is there a certain tool to create the coil around the terminal? What do I call this sort of terminal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called [Wire Wrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_wrap).  The low resistance connection is made by cold-welding the wire to the pin at the corners of the pin.

There is a special tool for making wire wrap connections.

[image]

Here's a [video about wire wrap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXvEDM-m9CE).  [Nothing special about it.  This is the first one I've come across.]